# How to change the call screen in android?

Tags: android

I am working dial-er kind of application. I have been breaking my min for a couple of months and trying to change the default out going call screen with my own custom screen which has all the options as it is in default caller screen. I tried making it and i succeeded now i have a problem with version 4.0 and above. When i tried to  show my custom screen the default dialer pop up for a few second and then my screen appears. I trying to stop it, but i am not able to do it. Can some one help me to get this done. Thanks in advance.